kaplan meier curve starting above 1 on the y-axis
I have computed a smoothed Kaplan Meier plot in R, by following this example in the comments by @agdamsbo link
I have copy pasted the same code as in the comment here:
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(purrr)
library(ggsurvfit)

## Data
df <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ surg, data = ggsurvfit::df_colon) |> ggsurvfit::tidy_survfit(type = "survival")

df_split <- split(df,df$strata)

df_smoothed <- purrr::reduce(lapply(c("estimate","conf.low", "conf.high"), function(j) {
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(seq_along(df_split), function(i) {
            nms <- names(df_split)[i]
            y <-
              predict(mgcv::gam(as.formula(paste0(
                j[[1]], " ~ s(time, bs = 'cs')"
              )), data = df_split[[i]]))
            df <- data.frame(df_split[[i]]$time, y, nms)
            names(df) <- c("time", paste0(j[[1]], ".smooth"), "strata")
            df
          }))
}),dplyr::full_join) |> full_join(df)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`

## Plotting
ggplot(data=df_smoothed) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=time, y=estimate.smooth, color = strata))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=time, ymin = conf.low.smooth, ymax = conf.high.smooth, fill = strata), alpha = 0.50)

The above codes works perfect, and I get a pretty smoothed kaplan meier plot, for each of the stratum (I have 4 groups). I can't use step functions as they can reveal micro data. Also, I can't share the smoothed Kaplan Meier plot from the above codes.
However, the curves for each stratum starts slightly above 1 on the y-axis. which does not make sense, as my sample size should be 100% at the beginning. I think it has something to do with the way it is coded due to the smoothing part of the curves.
What I have tried to do to fix the problem:
I have tried to incorporate codes from the cobs package into the codes from above, "to force" the curves to be flatten at 1 and to start from there. It almost worked for me, however, the KM plot I get only shows one stratum (I have 4 in total). Also, I have added weights in my survfit function, and I don't know how to incorporate the weights when using cobs.
Here is exactly what I have tried to do to fix it with cobs in R:
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
library(purrr)
library(ggsurvfit)

## Data
df <- survfit(Surv(time, outcome) ~ exposure+strata(sex), data = my_data) |> ggsurvfit::tidy_survfit(type = "survival")

df_split <- split(df,df$strata)

df_smoothed <- purrr::reduce(lapply(c("estimate","conf.low", "conf.high"), function(j) {
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(seq_along(df_split), function(i) {
            nms <- names(df_split)[i]
            y <-
              predict(mgcv::gam(as.formula(paste0(
                j[[1]], " ~ s(time, bs = 'cs')"
              )), data = df_split[[i]]))
            df <- data.frame(df_split[[i]]$time, y, nms)
            names(df) <- c("time", paste0(j[[1]], ".smooth"), "strata")
            df
          }))
}),dplyr::full_join) |> full_join(df)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`
#> Joining with `by = join_by(time, strata)`


library(cobs) ##NEW CODING STARTS FROM HERE

pw <- rbind(c( 1,min(df_smoothed1$time),1), 
          c(-1,max(df_smoothed$time),0)) 
x <- df_smoothed$time
y <- df_smoothed$estimate.smooth
ft <- cobs(x,y, constraint="decrease", nknots=4,pointwise= con2,
        degree = 2)
fit <- predict(ft, x) [, 'fit']

df_smoothed$x <- x
df_smoothed$y <- y
df_smoothed$fit <- fit

## Plotting
ggplot(data=df_smoothed, aes(x,y, color = strata)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=fit))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=time, ymin = conf.low.smooth, ymax = conf.high.smooth, fill = strata), alpha = 0.50)


A Kaplan Meier curve is, by definition, horizontal between event times.  If you smooth it to take away the steps, it's no longer a KM curve, and to call it such is, IMHO, misleading.  There are an infinite number of "smoothed KM" curves [sic], differing only in the manner in which they are smoothed.  A KM curve has a y value of 1 at time zero, again by definition.  The fact that your curve is not exactly one at t = 0 seems almost inevitable, given that the true KM estimate must, by definition, monotonically decrease from 1.

@Limey I agree with you in terms of a KM curve should be plotted as a step function, I completely understand it. But what if I'm not able to report the KM curve as it is originally (with the step function)? The step function can reveal micro data. I'm not permitted to report micro data. Therefore I got told that a smoothed version of the step function could be done, to "cover" the steps

Recognizing the above important caveats about whether or not this type of smoothing makes sense for a KM curve, you could do something like the below. You should note however, there is no guarrantee that the smoothed curve is monotonically decreasing - you would need further constraints to meet that requirement.
1. Data Prep

get dataset
create survfit object
create data frame of tidied values

## Data
data = ggsurvfit::df_colon %>% filter(surg=="Limited Time Since Surgery")

# create survfit object
df_surv <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ surg, data = data)

# tidy using tidy_survfit
df <- ggsurvfit::tidy_survfit(df_surv, type = "survival")

2. Create function that constrains a smooth to go through (0,1), and provides prediction of that smooth
constrain_0_1_smooth_km <- function(df,y,nknots=30, xinterval=c(0,10)) {
  knots <- data.frame(time = seq(xinterval[1],xinterval[2],length=nknots))
  sm <- smoothCon(s(time,k=nknots,bs="cr"),df,knots=knots)[[1]]
  sm$X[,1] <- 0
  sm$S[[1]][1,] <- 0
  sm$S[[1]][,1] <- 0
  predict(gam(df[[y]] ~ sm$X - 1 + offset(off),paraPen=list(X=list(sm$S[[1]]))))
}

3. Plot the original km, and the smoothed estimate along with smoothed conf.high and conf.low
# plot the KM curve
plot(df_surv, conf.int = F)
# add the smoothed version constrained at 0,1
lines(x = df$time, y=constrain_0_1_smooth_km(df, "estimate"),col="red")
lines(x = df$time, y=constrain_0_1_smooth_km(df, "conf.high"),col="blue")
lines(x = df$time, y=constrain_0_1_smooth_km(df, "conf.low"),col="blue")

Output:

You can instead plot with ggplot2 package of course, but I'll leave that to you, as I think the focus of the question is on how to constrain the smooth.
